# Shouldn't there be an explanation for a missing Edit Tag Wiki button?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-wiki

I just went to edit the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/mini-site/info) for [mini-site](/questions/tagged/mini-site) and noticed that the **Edit Tag Wiki** button is conspicuously missing.

[image: Tag Info for mini-site]

I believe that this is because twenty (?) questions need to use a tag before anyone (<20k rep) can suggest an edit to it, but this isn't mentioned anywhere on the Tag Info page. Can an explanation for the missing **Edit Tag Wiki** button be added to the Tag Info page? The current text is below.

> There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!
>
> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an
>   overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its
>   usage.
>
> All registered users may propose new tag wikis. Click the button below
>   to get started.
>
> (Note that if you have less than 20000 reputation, your tag wiki will
>   be peer reviewed before it is published.)

Comment: I have a pending edit for the tag summary. Perhaps this is related?

Comment: Ah, that might be it. In that case, perhaps the Tag Info page could indicate that there is a pending edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Came up with a fix:

If an edit is pending on a tag wiki, we now link to the [Approve or reject tag wiki edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) entry in Privileges if haven't enough rep to approve it.

Comment: @random: This is a bit . . . *random* . . . but is your name a description of your edit summaries?

Comment: @waffles Is this still in place? I don't see any such link when I look at [gprs], which I suspect currently has an edit pending: http://i.imgur.com/Qv8rR.png

Answer (score 4):

As Jeremy Banks noticed, there is a pending edit for that tag wiki: the one he proposed.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

As with other posts, users who don't have the [privilege of approving tag wiki edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) just don't see the "Edit Tag Wiki" button on the tag wiki page, nor do they see the "edit pending" link.

To notice that [on the meta site of other SE sites, it is not possible to edit the tag wikis](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129/it-is-not-possible-to-edit-a-tag-wiki-nor-create-one/132#132), as reported by Jeff Atwood in a question I asked.

> We aren't supporting tag wikis on per-site (child) metas right now -- we plan to push across all the standard meta tag wikis from meta.so regularly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be helpful to tell users who can't approve tag wiki edits that there is a pending edit preventing them from making a suggestion of their own?

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful. I got crazy trying to understand why I was not able to edit some posts, on a site where I didn't have the privilege of editing every post; at the end, I discovered (because Jeff answered to my question on the meta site for that site) that I would not see any "edit" link, if there are pending edits.