# What's going on with the [gprs] tag wiki?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-wiki

> Related: [Shouldn't there be an explanation for a missing Edit Tag Wiki button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103760/shouldnt-there-be-an-explanation-for-a-missing-edit-tag-wiki-button)

According to the above question, on every tag wiki page there should be one (and exactly one) of the following:

- a link to improve the wiki (in the case there is no pending suggested edit)
- a link to the FAQ (if there is a pending suggested edit)

On the [gprs](/questions/tagged/gprs) wiki, there is neither, at least as I see it:

---

[image: screenshot of gprs wiki]

---

I only noticed this just the other day, so it's possible (though probably unlikely at this point) that there is a suggested edit pending. However, if there is, why isn't there a link to the FAQ as mentioned in the question I linked above? Is the explanation for a missing Edit/Propose Tag Wiki button actually implemented?

Furthermore, [the revision history for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6869684/revisions) indicates that there *is* a wiki, but the tag info page doesn't seem to be aware of it. Is it possible that this has something to do with the fact that there is no excerpt for the tag?

Comment: The edit tag wiki button appears for me (a 30k+ user) but when I click it, nothing happens - I am apparently unable to edit the tag wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the underlying post got deleted by a moderator, fixed it with some direct db access. Confirmed there are no other tag wikis plagued with this.

Answer (score 4):

There is no suggested edit pending (at least not visible in the queue). The [wiki history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6869684/revisions) shows some text (but a tag wiki is not shown when there is no excerpt), while the [excerpt history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6869685/revisions) only shows a deletion by a moderator. I suppose there was some inappropriate text there.

Maybe this deletion caused a lock of the post, which makes it not-editable. I don't think this is wanted here, so maybe a moderator can undelete this post, to enable edits.

Anyway, I think this should be shown more clearly in the GUI.